# Changing CGRect for UIImageView in viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, viewdidload

I am sure I have come across this before but I can't remember what was causing it. I have positioned a UIImageView (bar_001) using a storyboard and I want to change its position programatically from within the viewController. My problem is that when accessed from viewDidLoad the UIImageViews size and origin are all just set to zero, what am I missing?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *bar_001;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self animateBars_V1];
}

- (void)animateBars_V1 {
    CGRect barRect = [[self bar_001] frame];
    NSLog(@"HEIGHT: %f", barRect.size.height);
    NSLog(@"WIDTH : %f", barRect.size.width);
}

@end
```

CONSOLE:

```
2012-12-11 12:53:27.777 TESTBED[4279:907] HEIGHT: 0.000000
2012-12-11 12:53:27.785 TESTBED[4279:907] WIDTH : 0.000000
```

STORYBOARD:

[image]

Comment: So what's your log of above code?

Comment: Is your `UIImageView` properly connected with your outlet ??

Comment: yes it is, because doing [[self bar_001] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; works and turns a white UIImageView green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have at times seen similar problem as well. I would try calling the animateBars_V1() method in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad. By the time, viewDidLoad is called the view is loaded in the memory but may not have been drawn. I would have to look somethings up before I can give a definite reason for why it behaves like this.

Comment: Thank you, It has to do with the viewController lifeCycle. When viewDidLoad is called all outlets have been instantiated and hooked up, but nothing is on screen yet, the view might not be the right size and the bounds have not been set. viewWillAppear is the right place to do this, everything is hooked up and sized and its right before the view is finally put on the screen. Thank you Numan, much appreciated.

Comment: The downside is that the user might be able to see objects being drawn to the screen late in viewDidAppear. At least, I was able to see a UILabel being drawn there, after the rest of the screen was displayed, in the simulator.